# trying to run flutter program and keep getting this error "the method 'HomeScreen' isn't defined for the type 'MyApp'

Tags: flutter

trying to run flutter program and keep getting this error "the method 'HomeScreen' isn't defined for the type 'MyApp' i need and answer to this problem quickly

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Food Delivery UI',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.grey[50],
        primaryColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You either didn't import the HomeScreen() or you don't have it

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss import file of HomeScreen at top of the main.dart.
HomeScreen class wasn't define in main.dart file as per your code.

Or maybe class name is something else. Check it again.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are Home Screen is in another .dart file. You'll need to import this dart file into your main.dart for it to work. Super easy fix just add this part at the top

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:<projectname>/lib/<subfolder if you have one>/HomeScreen.dart'

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 // This widget is the root of your application.
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Food Delivery UI',
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    theme: ThemeData(
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.grey[50],
      primaryColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
      
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    ),
    home: HomeScreen(),
  );
}
```

}